# Is "opinion" the new "subjective"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed several questions being retagged with [opinion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opinion).

Do we really need these meta-tags? I don't see any value in being able to, say, browse through all the opinions.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I only got part way through adding the tags; if anyone wants to help with the rest that would be great.

What will happen with those tags? I haven't the foggiest. But what I do know is that some people love subjective questions, and other people do not, and that as "subjective" leaves a negative impression, I used "opinion" instead.

Historically, other SE sites would not allow a tag like [tag:opinion]. However, they would also not allow questions like the ones it's been applied to. I believe that if we have one, we need the other.

I think that the [tag:opinion] and [tag:list] tags are a benefit to:

- the people who enjoy those types of questions, as they can find them more easily
- the people who would like SciFi.SE's questions to be more like those on other SE sites, as they can have that by ignoring those two tags

There's no judgment being made here (or at least not by me), and I'm not in a position to say if the [Good Subjective/Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective) rules will somehow come to not be applied here. But here and now, there are plenty of zeros and ones on that six point scale, and there needs to be a way to differentiate them.

<sub>Anyone know why my tag formatting doesn't work? I can't figure it out…</sub>

Comment: So, you tagged both opinion and list questions because they don't have a correct answer. This actually makes sense. Ok, if these questions do survive, we'll probably have to make them community wikis. I guess recommend-me questions would also fit to list.

Comment: If truly subjective questions that don't fit the SE subjective guidelines are allowed to remain open, the SE employees *will* close them down eventually. It's my opinion that, if this site is filled with such questions, this site will not make it out of beta.

Comment: @Dori - I believe the SE folks want these sites to run themselves as much as possible. We'll have pro-tem moderators appointed at some point to handle these kinds of things.

Comment: Some of the questions marked list, are not subjective for instance: What's actors have played Dr. Who? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/231/which-actors-have-played-dr-who-over-the-years is in every way a legitimate non-subjective question, but it is also a list.

Comment: @Dori Ok, sorry, I just wanted to make sure that distinction was being made.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like that's [Dori](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/100/dori)'s tag choice. I thank her for going through the questions and marking the subjective ones. We'll have to decide whether we want to keep these in a few days, and it's good to be able to find them quickly.

However I agree that it would be better to use `subjective` as is (or was) done on other Stack Exchange Sites.

Comment: Oh, I see. So, this isn't supposed to be a permanent tag. More like a convenience during beta phase.

Comment: @Goran: I don't know why Dori chose that tag, hopefully she'll pipe here. And maybe we'll end up keeping subjective questions, but that's a separate issue.