# Should we kill the opinion tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

In [Is “opinion” the new “subjective”?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71/is-opinion-the-new-subjective), it would seem the community decided to keep the tag around because it could be used to ignore this type of questions. However, two weeks later, only four out of the 24 questions tagged with the opinion tag are still open. I think, at this point, we can conclude that, given their low frequency, such questions are not really going to be a problem.

Moreover, [this questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/621/how-fast-should-mutations-be-for-hard-science-fiction) tagged with opinion have answers so good that the opinion tag does the question just a disservice. It hardly falls as an opinion, IMO.

So, should we kill the opinion tag now?

Comment: Yes, please.  Right now.  Blacklist it and publicly flog anyone who tries to use it again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image]